# Can I have a heterogeneous collection in Realm Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I would like to have an object that is an ordered collection of multiple different kinds of Realm Objects, like so...

```
public class One: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
}

public class Two: Object {
    dynamic var label = ""
}

public class Listing: Object {
    let onesAndTwos = List<Object>()
}
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

I know I can add an Enum-like wrapper object...

```
public class OneOrTwo: Object {
    dynamic var one: One?
    dynamic var two: Two?
}

public class Listing: Object {
    let onesAndTwos = List<OneOrTwo>()
}
```

But I'd like to avoid that indirection, if possible.

Comment: I don't know much about realm, but if it's based on a database table, then no, probably not. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to make a list of steps in a process where there are different kinds of steps. Each kind of step stores different information.

Comment: This is a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/q/45621/3141234

Comment: Thanks, I understand how to do this in a table-based database. It's not clear to me whether realm *is* table-based, or is a object-graph datastore, where this would be possible.

Comment: Yeah, I would be interested to see the answers this question yields

Comment: Just guessing, based on names, but there's a DataType called Link, that seems to define the origin and target tables on a per-Link basis, not a per-column basis... https://github.com/realm/realm-core/blob/master/src/realm/link_view.hpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<T>` property can't contain objects of different types.

Please learn more in docs at https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships and https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#model-inheritance, that should explain why it's not possible.

So I suggest you to use composition over inheritance, basically the same way as you mentioned in your post.